# Sticky position kills scrollbars in chrome 77 (osx)

Tags: html, css

In the example below I have two tables except the first one has a sticky header which I achieve with

```
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
```

https://codepen.io/seunje/pen/JjjRVLm

The sticky-ness works very well but the scrollbars disappear!
This works fine in Firefox.

Does anyone know a work-around in Chrome?

```css
.container {
  height: 50px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.tr.sticky-header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}
.td.sticky-header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}
.tr {
  display: table-row;
}
.td {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="tr sticky-header">
      <div class="td sticky-header">H1</div>
      <div class="td sticky-header">H2</div>
      <div class="td sticky-header">H3</div>
      <div class="td sticky-header">H4</div>
      <div class="td sticky-header">H5</div>
    </div>
        <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">1</div>
      <div class="td">2</div>
      <div class="td">3</div>
      <div class="td">4</div>
      <div class="td">5</div>
    </div>
        <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">1</div>
      <div class="td">2</div>
      <div class="td">3</div>
      <div class="td">4</div>
      <div class="td">5</div>
    </div>
        <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">1</div>
      <div class="td">2</div>
      <div class="td">3</div>
      <div class="td">4</div>
      <div class="td">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="tr header">
      <div class="td header">H1</div>
      <div class="td header">H2</div>
      <div class="td header">H3</div>
      <div class="td header">H4</div>
      <div class="td header">H5</div>
    </div>
        <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">1</div>
      <div class="td">2</div>
      <div class="td">3</div>
      <div class="td">4</div>
      <div class="td">5</div>
    </div>
        <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">1</div>
      <div class="td">2</div>
      <div class="td">3</div>
      <div class="td">4</div>
      <div class="td">5</div>
    </div>
        <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">1</div>
      <div class="td">2</div>
      <div class="td">3</div>
      <div class="td">4</div>
      <div class="td">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to have scrollbars and position: sticky working on same element. Check the code, first table scrolls and has sticky header but scrollbars are not there! Second table scrolls with the header and scrollbars are there. I suppose there are different ways to achieve sticky-header but I am wondering if there is something I am not doing/doing wrongly here

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a background to the header and give to it a higher z-index, this way you'll have the header always in evidence